# 'getWorkManagerConfiguration' overrides nothing

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to inject WorkManager with Hilt as shown in the below link
https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager

and I got stuck when I was implementing `Configuration.Provider` interface as below

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class ExampleApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

  @Inject lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

  override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
      Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
}
```

I am getting "getWorkManagerConfiguration overrides nothing" error.
I have no idea why it can't implement the getter of the Configuration.Provider interface

```
interface Provider {
    /**
     * The [Configuration] used to initialize WorkManager
     */
    val workManagerConfiguration: Configuration
}
```

This is the error I get:
[image: error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it all, you try to override `fun getWorkManagerConfiguration()`, but there is no function with that name.

There is a *val property* (not a *function*) that can be overridden, and it has another name, `workManagerConfiguration`. So what you probably want to do is:

```
override val workManagerConfiguration: Configuration = ...
```

You do not even have to do this manually. As can be seen from your screenshot, `class MyApplication` also has an error. There is a quick fix "Implement Members" for that error that automatically implements all missing members. Use it to generate the code above.

Comment: thank you for the reply! I don't have much experience in Kotlin. I thought Kotlin auto-generates the getter & setter for the property so I thought I should be able to override the getter function of the val, but that is not true in this case?

Comment: Kotlin does not just auto-generate getter and setter, it also lets you access all getter and setter as though they were properties. Take a look at the class `java.util.Date` for example. It has a `getTime()` and a `setTime()` function. Using Kotlin, you can access *both* functions by the virtual property `time`: `Date().time + 1000` calls the getter under the hood and `Date().time = 1000` calls the setter. ...

Comment: ...  If you would want to override these, you would indeed need to override the functions as `override fun getTime(): Long` and `override fun setTime(time: Long)`. The interface from your question, however, is a Kotlin interface that has a real property `workManagerConfiguration`. Although getter and setter are generated (mainly so that Java code can access it), you can only override the property itself. Since you can use the IDE to assist you with implementing and overriding members, this behavior shouldn't be too confusing.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for the explanations. they helped a lot!